# How to invoke a method in interface using reflection

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

I have a class and that class 'class1' is implementing an interface interface1

I need to invoke a method in the class using the reflection.

I can't use the class name and interface name as it is because both the name will change dynamically.`

`interface1 objClass = (interface1 )FacadeAdapterFactory.GetGeneralInstance("Class"+ version);`

See the above code snippet. The class name and the interface name should change according to its version. I have created the instance for class by using

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Class1"))
```

but i m not able to crete the same for interface

Is there any way to implement the above context.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create instance of interface, just class that implements interface.
There are some ways to extract method (info) from interface.

```
ISample element = new Sample();

Type iType1 = typeof(ISample);
Type iType2 = element.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Single(e => e.Name == "ISample");
Type iType3 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Single(e => e.Name == "ISample" && e.IsInterface == true);

MethodInfo method1 = iType1.GetMethod("SampleMethod");
MethodInfo method2 = iType2.GetMethod("SampleMethod");
MethodInfo method3 = iType3.GetMethod("SampleMethod");

method1.Invoke(element, null);
method2.Invoke(element, null);
method3.Invoke(element, null);
```

I hope it's sufficient.

Comment: I cannot use the statement like ISample element = new Sample(); because the name ISample will change dynamically. I m passing version number. The interface name will change with respect to the version number like  ISample1, ISample2 etc...

Comment: Ok, but you can easily use:

Type iType2 = element.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Single(e => e.Name == "ISample"); or
Type iType3 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Single(e => e.Name == "ISample" && e.IsInterface == true);
Just edit string - "ISample" - concat it with version.